# "Bieten" oder "anbieten" in "Eine Firma bietet etwas (an)"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verb

Welches Verb ist gebräuchlicher, *bieten* oder *anbieten*?

> Eine Firma bietet die Möglichkeit, ... zu tun.
>   Eine Firma bietet die Möglichkeit an, ... zu tun.

Comment: Das hängt vom Kontext ab, m. a. W. Du mußt genauer beschreiben, was Du sagen willst.

Comment: Man kann beides sagen; willst du wirklich nur wissen, welches Wort häufiger gebraucht wird, oder interessiert dich, ob es einen (wenn auch nur kleinen) Bedeutungsunterschied in diesem Fall gibt?

Comment: @Maasumi Ich ginge davon aus, es gibt keinen Unterschied dazwischen. Gibt es den doch, dann würde ich gern den wissen!

Comment: @MartinPeters ich will beschreiben, dass eine Firma eine Möglichkeit ermöglicht

Comment: @RomanT Das hab ich nur so gefragt, um der Frage Intention herauszufinden.
Man könnte sich eventuell aus der Vorsilbe einen Unterschied basteln (eher forciert).

Comment: Eine Möglichkeit ermöglicht? Eine mögliche Möglichkeit gar möglicherweise ermöglicht? :) Ernste Fragen: Schriftlicher oder mündlicher Sprachgebrauch? Wie soll man das wissen? Wenn schriftlich, nur Literatur, oder auch Presse? Auch Geschäftskorrespondenz? Wie soll man letzteres wissen? Beides ist gebräuchlich - fertig. Mehr kann man, gerade bei schlecht suchbaren Wendungen, nicht sagen. Nur subjektives Gestümper abgeben (aber das wird gerne getan).

Comment: @userunknown schriftliche Geschäftskorrespondenz (E-Mails, JIRA-Tickets)

Comment: @RomanT: Darüber gibt es kaum eine Statistik. Es kann also jeder mit dem antworten, was er meint beobachtet zu haben, was schwerlich representatitv sein wird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bieten* und *anbieten* überschneiden sich in ihrer Bedeutung sind aber nicht identisch, daher ergibt es keinen Sinn zu sagen was "gebräuchlicher ist. Wiktionary ([1](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anbieten), [2](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bieten)) und Duden ([3](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anbieten), [4](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bieten)) listen beide diverse Bedeutungen und Beispiele auf.

Bei deinem Beispiel würde ich die Wahl *anbieten* oder *bieten* vom Objekt abhängig machen. *Was* wird geboten?

Der Duden hat für [bieten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bieten) unter anderem folgende Beispiele:

> - jemandem Geld, eine Chance, einen Ersatz für etwas bieten
> - etwas bietet jemandem eine Möglichkeit (etwas ermöglicht    jemandem etwas)

Der Duden hat für [anbieten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anbieten) unter anderem folgende Beispiele:

> - jemandem seine Hilfe, seinen Platz, seine Dienste anbieten
> - er bot ihr an, sie nach Hause zu fahren

Ausgehend von den Beispielen (in Übereinstimmung mit meinem Bauchgefühl), würde ich *anbieten* eher nehmen, wenn es um eine konkrete Sache handelt:

- Eine Firma **bietet** die Möglichkeit, die Ware nach Hause zu liefern.
- Eine Firma **bietet an**, die Ware nach Hause zu liefern.
- Eine Firma **bietet** einen Lieferservice **an**.